# Reading each line of text file and storing into columns in a CSV file using Perl

Tags: perl

I have a text file where file content has delimiter as space in beginning. 
Its like below:

- First line doesn't have any space in beginning.
- Second line has 2 space.
- Third line has 4 space in the beginning.
- Fourth line has 6 spaces in the beginning.

Again this pattern is repeated till end of file in a random way as shown in text file eg below.

I want to read these lines from the text file and save the lines in pattern:

- having no space in first column.
- having 2 spaces in second column.
- 4 spaces in third column.
- 6 spaces in fourth column of a CSV file.

The text file structure is (representing spaces by #) :

```
ABC
##EFG"123"
####<HIJK> 22: test file
######LMNOP "Test"
######sssstt"123"
QRS
##TU"223"
####<www> 32: test2 file
######yz test1
####<www> 88: test3 file
######rreeeww
######oooiiiii
##PP
##ss
####<qqq> 89: test6 file
######hhhhggg
######bbbbaaa
######cccczzz
######uu test3
```

Expected output image:
[image: output]

I am new to Perl, I know how to open a file and read through line but I am not understanding how to store this kind of structure in CSV columns.

```
my $file = 'C:\\outputfile.txt';
open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $file) or die "Could not open file '$file' $!"; 
while (my $row = <$fh>) { # reading each row till end of file
    chomp $row;  
    //what should be done here ?
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Please copy the example file into your question, instead of giving an image.  That way someone who wants to help can use it for testing.

Comment: You don't explain what should happen if there are multiple lines beginning with the same number of spaces. I suggest you show the output you require from the input you have posted.

Comment: @Borodin Hm, read a question, please. Author said, that double spaces - delimiter in his file

Comment: @loldop: Yes, that much is clear. But it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Hi, I have edited my question with image of the expected output. If I try to copy the output as text its changing the format of the output while saving. So adding as image.

Comment: I can't see CSV in expected output. The C stands for comma, you know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have questions about code, I will say: yes, I can answer, but this is not good or the best example of Perl code. Just fast to write.

```
my $previous_count = "-1"; #beginning, we will think, that no spaces.
my $current_count = "0";  #current default value
my $maximum_count = 3; #u say so
my $to_written = "";
my $delimiter_between_columns = ",";
my $newline_separator = ";";
my $symbol_at_the_beginning = "#"; #input any symbol. But I suppose, you want "\s" <- whitespace' symbol class. input it like this: $var = "\s";
my @aggregate_array_of_ports=();
while(my $row = <DATA>){
#ok, read.    
chomp($row);    
#print "row is : $row\n";
if($row =~ m/^([$symbol_at_the_beginning]*)/){
   #print length($1);
   $current_count = length($1) / 2; #take number of spaces divided by 2
   $row =~ s/^[$symbol_at_the_beginning]+//;
   #hint here, we can get counts as 0,1,2,3 <-see? 
   #if you take first and third word, you need to add 2 separators.
   #OR if you take count with LESSER then previous count, it mean, that you need output       
   #print"prev : $previous_count   and    curr : $current_count\n  ";
   #print"I will write: $to_written\n";
   #print "\n PREV: $previous_count --> CURR: $current_count \n";
   if($previous_count>=$current_count){
      #output here
      print "$to_written".$newline_separator."\n";
      $previous_count = 0;
      $to_written = "";
   }
   $previous_count = 0 if($previous_count==-1);   

   #print "$delimiter_between_columns x($current_count-$previous_count)\n";
   #print "current: $current_count previous: $previous_count \n";
   $to_written .= $delimiter_between_columns x ($current_count - $previous_count + (($current_count-$previous_count)==3?2:0) )."$row";
   if ($current_count==($maximum_count-1)){
    #print "I input this!: $to_written\n";
    $to_written = prepare_to_input_four_spaces($to_written, $delimiter_between_columns);    
    }
   $previous_count = $current_count;
   #print"\n";
}
}
  #print "$to_written".$newline_separator."\n";
sub prepare_to_input_four_spaces{
    my $str = shift; #take string
    my $delim = shift;
    if ($str=~ m/(.+?[>])\s+(\d+)[:]\s+(.+?)$/){
    #here I want to find first capture group before [>] (also it includes) |(.+?[>])|
    #next, some spaces |\s+| and I want to catch port |(\d+)|.
    #next, |[:]| symbol and some spaces again |\s+| before the tail of the string.
    #and will catch this tail: |(.+?)$|.
    #where $ mean the right "border" of the string (really - end of the string)
        $str = $1.$delim.$2.$delim.$3;
        }
        return $str;
    }

=pod
__DATA__
ABC
  EFG"123"
    HIJK (12345)
      LMNOP "Test"
      sssstt"123"
QRS
  TU"223"
    vwx"55"
    www"88"
      yz:test1
__END__
=cut
__DATA__
ABC
##EFG"123"
####<HIJK> 22: test file
######LMNOP "Test"
######sssstt"123"
QRS
##TU"223"
####<www> 32: test2 file
######yz test1
####<www> 88: test3 file
######rreeeww
######oooiiiii
##PP
##ss
####<qqq> 89: test6 file
######hhhhggg
######bbbbaaa
######cccczzz
######uu test3
```

Comment: @KaushambiSuyal Hi! If my answer really helps you, I will be glad to see your "accepts/upvotes" for my answer. This is good behavior for Stack Overflow

Comment: Hi, there is bit of update in my expected output. I have modified my question in the input and output images.For the line starting with 4 spaces, I need it to further split it into 3 columns as I have shown in expected output. Rest all remains same as it was before. I am not pasting my code as its very much similar to yours. COuld you please help me in doing so ?

Comment: @KaushambiSuyal yes, I can help, but, please, tell why yztest1 is not in last line? and how I can detect ports(`\d\d[:]`) and separate them. strange output, I need more information and examples. Can you provide them?

Comment: My mistake,I have updated the output like YZtest2 in last line as well.Yes, its strange output as this comes from command.For port detection:I have identified 3 delimiters for the line starting with 4 spaces.We can put a loop.If the line has 4 spaces,find the closing bracket(>)and split and push the number next to it(eg:22)in a next column and then if it has a colon,again split and push it to next column.Is that possible? But it should not disturb the other rows. Like lines having 6 spaces in the beginning should always go in one column as they have been working currently.Is that helpful?

Comment: splitting line is not trouble, trouble was in 4-6 spaces lines. They not connected as I expected at the beginning of this solution. But this is possible to make, of course. Please, add example if you have three 4spaces lines and four 6spaces lines. And opposite: four 4spaces lines and three 6spaces lines. Which is possible? And what output suspected?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I have updated the example (input and expected output). May be it would bring more clarity. If there is a line with 4 spaces, there would definitely be line with 6 spaces.Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: I haven't checked the code yet but I just found that you had updated it. Just to mention, I have denoted the space with hash (#). I found that you have stored # in a variable. # is just for denoting spaces in the question. Also if you could put some comments, it will be easy for me to understand especially at the pattern matching. thanks.

Comment: Hey buddy! You are a champ! thanks alot. I just made few modifications as per my requirement and it worked the way I needed. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @KaushambiSuyal No problems. if you really glad, please, leave "accept" for my answer ;) (green stick under vote-arrows)

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is ok for you:
I just skipped putting the header and had put the separator as "|".you can any how change it.

```
> perl -lne 'if(/^[^\#]/){if($.!=1){print "$a"};$a=$_;}else{s/^#*//g;$a.="|$_";}END{print $a}' temp
ABC|EFG"123"|HIJK (12345)|LMNOP "Test"|sssstt"123"
QRS|TU"223"|vwx"55"|www"88"|yz:test1
```

Comment: Hi, could you please explain more in detail on how the above code would work? Also, its not # actually, its the space, I have denoted it by hash.